# How to get a key to be used as a variable in a lodash map function?

Tags: javascript, lodash

I'm trying to restructure an object for convience.

This is the general structure:

```
 var dictionary = { "word": {"content": "wordy"}, "palabra": {"content":"palabrota" }};
```

I want it to look like this:

```
 [{"wordy":"word"},{"palabrota":"palabra"}]
```

And I'm trying this code out:

```
_.map(dictionary, function(v,k){ var new_key = v.content;return { new_key: k };} );
```

But instead of what I am expecting, this is the result:

```
[ { new_key: 'word' }, { new_key: 'palabra' } ]
```

How to get a key to be used as a variable in this function?

Comment: Why not just, `var rtn = {}; rtn[v.content] = k; return rtn;`?

Comment: :). That works! A little bit confusing to interpret since I am not seeing your function in there, but it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`_.invertBy` method](https://lodash.com/docs#invertBy) (as of LoDash v4.1.0), which will give you the key and an array of the values, thus ensuring the values aren't overwritten.

```
var dictionary = {
  "word": {"content": "wordy"},
  "anotherWord": {"content": "wordy"},
  "palabra": {"content":"palabrota" }
};

var result = _.invertBy(dictionary, function(item) {
  return item.content;
});

// "{"wordy":["word","anotherWord"],"palabrota":["palabra"]}"
```

---

EDIT: earlier response below. This works, however the limitation is duplicate content values would overwrite the keys. The docs for `_.transform` below shows how to generate an array to handle duplicates, and a similar setup can be used for the regular JS approach.

You can use the [`_.transform` method](https://lodash.com/docs#transform):

```
var transformedResult = _.transform(dictionary, function(result, value, key) {
    return result[value.content] = key;
});
```

Or without LoDash at all, you can construct the object as intended.

```
var result = {};
Object.keys(dictionary).forEach(function(key) {
    var value = dictionary[key].content;
    result[value] = key;
});
```

Comment: Technically this isn't what I asked for, but it is what I want. Transform is a beautiful method! Thinking about a way to get exactly what I want, say I there were 2, "v.content" which were equal to each other.

Comment: @ovatsug25 you didn't mention grouping in this manner in your question, technically :) So if you had multiple `v.content` of the same value, what result do you want? An array such as `{ wordy: ['word1', 'word2']}` ? If that's the case, the link to the `_.transform` in the docs above matches your request exactly. It builds an array using the value and pushes the keys.

Comment: @ovatsug25 I've updated my response showing how to handle this case with `_.invertBy`

Answer (score 1):

I might recommend `_.mapValues(dictionary, "content")` for simplicity.

However, instead of `[{"wordy":"word"},{"palabrota":"palabra"}]`, instead you'll get `{"wordy": "word", "palabrota": "palabra"}` as the result from `_.mapValues`.  But given that you're using lodash, and lodash treats arrays and objects pretty much interchangeably, I think the non-array version would be more convenient.